# Insight data from API for a page: Where do I get page Id?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-insights

I'm really confused so I hope you guys can help me. I know how to access the API with an app since I have all those information like app secret and API key. But what should I do with a standard page? Like https://www.facebook.com/NASAKennedy

We created many pages that are not apps. I couldn't find any API information on how to retrieve insights data. I'd like to get the numbers of likes per day and numbers of posts.

So in short, if I create a page here: https://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php can we access its insights information from the API?

Thanks,

Stéphane

Comment: I found this, but it's for the deprecated offline_access... http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2816156/facebook-insights-for-page-via-the-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

Refference URLs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/

https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=217014154989455

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Am I missing something? I already read that, but still can't find where to get the page ID. For example, for https://www.facebook.com/NASAKennedy, the page username is NASAKEnnedy, but where do I get the page ID?

Comment: 1. you can get the page id manually..go to edit and see the page id. 2. as per facebook,  insights will be available only after gettings 30 likes for the page..see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/ 3. you can use that page id in your API

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know which page-ID your facebook page has, do the following:

- just open the Graph Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
- Add the username "NASAKennedy" in the Input field besides "GET" and send your request.

Now you will see a JSON-Object with basic informations about the page. Look inside this Text and search for "id:". There you will read the page-ID.